# How do i query date range comparisions in sharepoint 2013 list using JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-addin, jquery, jsom, datetimecontrol

I need to compare date ranges the result should be between start date and end date. I am using

`Sharepoint:DateTimeControl` picker and get the date using jquery,

then converted date like

```
startDate  =  startDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(startDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+startDate.getDate()+'T00:00:01Z';  

endDate = endDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(endDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+endDate.getDate()+'T00:00:01Z';
```

The below is my query for comparisions

```
<Geq>
    <FieldRef Name="Created" />
    <Value IncludeTimeValue="FALSE" Type="DateTime">2015-5-28T00:00:01Z</Value>
</Geq>
<Leq>
    <FieldRef Name="Created" />
    <Value IncludeTimeValue="FALSE" Type="DateTime">2015-7-8T00:00:01Z</Value>
</Leq>
```

I am getting error

> "Value doesnot fall within the range exception"

Comment: IDK if it will matter, but the May and July months should be zero padded to comply with UTC format

Comment: Thanks for the reply !!!. can you pls explain how can i achieve that. ?